# How to clear Invalid input in Oracle-Apex Item before page submit?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a page Item P1_USERNAME, and when a user enter some text I want to clear the text that is not allowed before submitting the page.

Say like user enters sra>{563< after the entry is complete, the text should look like sra by clearing all the input after 'a' since > is defined not valid.

Comment: i gave you the answer - pls remember to upvote!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a Dynamic Action - Change type, that fires when the field is changed and then loses focus. You would then execute JavaScript code in response to the event that would parse and replace the text. Docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/advnc_dynamic_actions.htm#HTMDB27020).

Change (change) - Fires when a control loses the input focus and its value has been modified since gaining focus. Supported User Interface Types: Desktop and jQuery Mobile Smartphone.

Specify the action that is performed when the previously specified event occurs and conditions are satisfied:

Execute JavaScript Code - Enables you to define or call custom, page specific JavaScript code to use within the dynamic action framework. If you are defining JavaScript code that is specific to just one page, you can also make use of the new page level attribute Function and Global Variable Declaration to define this. Functions and variables defined here can subsequently be referenced from this action.

You want all this client side - so the parse and replace must be done in a JS function that you write.

If you wanted to get super fancy, use the Dynamic Action Key Press and monitor the chars being entered. If they enter an invalid character, you can popup a JS message and prevent them from typing more bad chars: Key Press (keypress) - Fires when a key on the keyboard is pressed resulting in text being entered. Use this event when you want to capture actual text entry.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a computation that fires After Submit and uses a PL/SQL expression like:

```
case when instr(:P1_USERNAME,'>') > 0 
  then substr(:P1_USERNAME, 1, instr(:P1_USERNAME,'>')-1) 
  else :P1_USERNAME
  end
```

This will fire after submit but before other processing.

If your computation needs to be more complex you could move the code to a package function and make the computation like:

```
my_pkg.cleanup (:P1_USERNAME)
```

Comment: hi tony....but this computation should occur before the page is submitted!!! something like client side validation...

Comment: Why?  What will go wrong if it happens at submit time instead?

Comment: the requirement says that way!! It want users not type any incorrect character, as soon as user leaves the filed it should clear incorrect entries.